# How to increase Server-Sent Event's reopen time?

Tags: php, timeout, server-sent-events

I'm working to show notifications from Server-Sent Event. I checked that every time the browser tries to reconnect with the source about 3 seconds after each connection is closed. That event is getting a call too fast, so my server is loaded too.

So how do I change the reopening time to increase? I have to do at least 60 seconds, so tell me how to do it?

I'm trying the following code.

```html
<table class="table" id="notification"></table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ssevent = null;
    if (!!window.EventSource) {
        ssevent = new EventSource('ssevent.php');

        ssevent.addEventListener('message', function(e){
            if(e.data){
                json = JSON.parse(e.data);
                if(json){
                    json.forEach(function(v,i){
                        html = "<tr><td>"+ v.text +"</td><td>"+ v.date +"</td></tr>";
                    });
                    $('#notification').append(html);
                }
            }
        }, false);

        ssevent.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
            if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED){
                console.log("Connection was closed.");
            }
        }, false);
    } else {
        console.log('Server-Sent Events not support in your browser');
    }
</script>
```

The file of event stream is as follow.

```php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

include_once "config.php";
$time = isset($_SESSION['last_event_time']) ? $_SESSION['last_event_time'] : time();

$result = $db->quesry("SELECT * FROM event_noti WHERE event_time < {$time} ")->rows;
$_SESSION['last_event_time'] = time();

if($result){
    $json = array();
    foreach ($result as $row){
        $json[] = array(
            'text' => $row['event_text'],
            'date' => date("Y-m-d H:i", $row['event_time']),
        );
    }

    echo "data: ". json_encode($json) . "\n\n";
    flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Now I have my answer.*

---

### Controlling Reconnection-Timeout:

The browser attempts to reconnect the connection to the source within about 3 seconds after each server-sent event connection is closed. Before trying to reconnect, you can change that timeout by starting the line with `retry:` and then adding the millisecond number to wait.

I changed the code below and started working as I wanted.

```php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

include_once "config.php";
$time = isset($_SESSION['last_event_time']) ? $_SESSION['last_event_time'] : time();

$result = $db->quesry("SELECT * FROM event_noti WHERE event_time < {$time} ")->rows;
$_SESSION['last_event_time'] = time();

echo "retry: 60000\n"; // 60 seconds, to wait for next connection.

$json = array();
if($result){
    foreach ($result as $row){
        $json[] = array(
            'text' => $row['event_text'],
            'date' => date("Y-m-d H:i", $row['event_time']),
        );
    }
}

echo "data: ". json_encode($json) . "\n\n";
flush();
```

[Source from](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/#toc-reconnection-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally you cannot control this: it is a browser-specific setting.

If your browser is Firefox it appears to be controlled by this setting: `dom.server-events.default-reconnection-time`  with a default of 5000ms.

Taking a step back: the reconnect only happens if the *server* closes the connection. Why are you closing the connection? (*) Why is a 3-second re-connection too fast?

The point of SSE is to minimize latency; the trade-off is more resource usage, in particular having to keep a dedicated socket open for each client.

So it sounds like you don't want to be using SSE, and instead want to use a simple AJAX poll, on a 60-second `setInterval()` call?

*: If you did intend to keep it open, you need to wrap your query and processing the result code in a `while(true){...}` loop. Put e.g. a one-second sleep at the end of the while loop to stop the DB server being overloaded.